# Egit / Eclipse: Share an existing project with an external repository without moving the original folder

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have been working on a project, then i did:

```
share > team > git
```

It suddenly moved the project to another folder. Nevertheless I don't want it to be moved or create a repository on top of my eclipse projects because by experience I know mixing everything is a bad idea.

Am I am correct to say that I have to move the working directory to the Repository if i want to use Egit?

Thank you for your help

Comment: The standard way here is to mix things :-) You store the repo in your Eclipse workspace (or at an external location), but you should develop within the version controlled project. Things get messed up easily the other way.

Comment: Thank you, so your suggestion is that i create the repository within the eclipse workspace.

Comment: Yes, something like that. The best is to create a folder under the workspace and store the git repo there so you don't need different Eclipse workspaces for all your projects. The issue with multiple workspaces is that lot of settings are stored per-WS (e.g., hotkeys, which is a PITA to always import-export).